# .htaccess url rewrite challenge with query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Have a little challenge. I'm have trouble adding another "filter" to my current rewrite code. I want to add another rewrite that captures the query string at the end of the url (if supplied)

Example..

```
example.com/search/?sort=newest   -->   example.com/search.php?sort=newest
example.com/search/first?sort=newest   -->   example.com/search.php?a=first&sort=newest
example.com/search/first/second?sort=newest   -->   example.com/search.php?a=first&b=second&sort=newest
example.com/search/first/second/third?sort=newest   -->   example.com/search.php?a=first&b=second&c=third&sort=newest
```

This is my current code.

```
# search without filters
RewriteRule    ^search?$    search/    [NC,L]

# search with one filter
RewriteRule    ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)?$    search.php?a=$1    [NC,L]

# search with two filters
RewriteRule    ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)?$    search.php?a=$1&b=$2    [NC,L]

# search with three filters
RewriteRule    ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)?$    search.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3    [NC,L]
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Well, I haven't figured out how to capture the sort parameter and redirect it to the php file with a get variable.

`example.com/search?sort=newest`
should redirect to..
`example.com/search.php?sort=newest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep an existing query string in a `RewriteRule`, you don't need to do anything.

But if you add a query string yourself in the substitution part, you need to use the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag to append the previous query string

```
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-+]+)?$ search.php?a=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Perfect answer, got me right on track, works perfectly now.